# How to properly mix cooked noodles and vegetables?

Tags: noodles

Whenever I make basic noodles & vegetable dishes I would cook the noodles in a pot of water, while at the same time stir frying vegetables in a wok.

Then when the cooking is done, I would drain the water out of the noodles and add them to the vegetables.

The problem is that they don't mix properly; the cooked noodles stick together too much for me to be able to blend them with the vegetables.

This usually means I end up with a thick layer of noodles with some minor vegetables on top, and a thick layer of vegetables at the bottom of the wok.

It's still tasty, but I'd like to know if there's a way to make the mixing process easier so that the dish becomes more uniform in taste.

Comment: Not a proper answer so I'm including in comments. I find it easier to break the noodles into shorter pieces before cooking since they mix easier. This is especially true with something like bean thread (translucent) noodles.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you mean cooked asian noodles and not Italian pasta as the two problems are different. One thing is to make sure you are boiling the noodles in plenty of water as this will reduce the starch on the noodles which cause sticking, or rinse the noodles after cooking to wash the starch off. Next, make sure the stir fry mix isn't too dry, moisture will help the flavors distribute and lubricate the noodles, helping keep them apart. You can always add a small amount of water, it won't ruin anything. Last, use two spoons to mix the noodles up, grap bunches of noodles to pull them apart. Alternatively you can use tongs, the result is the same but I find 2 spoons quicker.

Comment: Yes, asian noodles indeed.

Answer (score 3):

If your noodles are sticking to each other, toss the noodles with a tiny bit of oil before mixing with the vegetables.

Tossing the noodles with a sauce before mixing with the vegetables should also help.